# Javascript- Matching values from array to substring of variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to match values from an array to a variable string.
So if, for example, I have an array and a variable :

```
var array = ['Potato', 'Cheese', 'Bikini', 'Truck', 'Express'];
var something = 'Potato Thief';
```

I would like my function to return "True" since the variable includes 'Potato' in the array.

I currently have something like this at the moment...

```
if(array.indexOf(something)!=-1)
{
true;
}
else
{
false;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you having a specific problem? Also, if you want to return a value, you must include the `return` keyword before it. E.g. `return true;`. Finally, instead of `if ( /* */ ) { return true; } else { return false; }`, you can simply do `if ( /* */ ) { return true; } return false;`, as the function will exit at the return keyword, and will only reach one of the returns.

Comment: Hi yeah, when I run the indexOf I get a false for 'Potato Thief'. But a true for 'Potato'. I think it's b/c of the second part of the string is not in the array.

Comment: Oh! I Misread that. If you want to see if a string that is in the array is in the provided string, you need to reverse that. As it's written now, you're searching the array to see if it contains `'Potato Thief'`, which it does not.

Comment: No worries. Hmm, something.indexOf(array)!=-1 isn't working either... Would I need to somehow split/separate the strings?

Comment: You'll need to iterate over them. Something like Thamira's solution. You could also use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to iterate until a match is found, which would tell you _if_ there's a match, but not which one matched.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37647025/fastest-way-to-compare-a-string-with-a-array-of-strings/

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I figured it out. Did something  like

Answer (score 2):

you don't need an if statement for it

```
return array.indexOf(something)!=-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You have to loop the array and match array elements with the given string

```
 var array = ['Potato', 'Cheese', 'Bikini', 'Truck', 'Express'];
        var something = 'Potato Thief';


        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 

            if(something.search(array[i]) == 0){
                console.log(true);
            }else{
                console.log(false);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this like as follows;

```js
var array = ['Potato', 'Cheese', 'Bikini', 'Truck', 'Express'],
something = 'Potato Thief',
     test = array.some(e => something.includes(e));
console.log(test)
```